# Memoir appendix

Tags: memoir, appendices, babel

At the moment I have Appendix A when I start the appendix page. In the table of contexts I see the item A. How can I replace the "A" by "Appendix". I'm using the memoir class and I'm also using babel but I was already able to change the appendix name as follows.

```
\addto\captionsdutch{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixname}%
    {Appendix}%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is the problem in that you have only *one* appendix and don't want it "numbered" by a letter?

Comment: exactly. I still want to have the figures in the appendix to be with labels like Figuur A.1 sometexthere instead of Figuur .1 when I remove the numbering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, to add the word "Appendix" in the ToC, you can redefine `\cftappendixname`; if you also want to suppress the numbering for the appendix (both in the ToC and in the body of the document), you can redefine `\thechapter` just before the appendix (and adjust `\cftchapternumwidth`). Here's a little example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\addto\captionsdutch{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixname}%
    {Appendix}%
}
\renewcommand*\cftappendixname{\appendixname}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Test Regular Chapter}
\appendix

\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{1em}}
\renewcommand\thechapter{}
\chapter{Test Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I need but when I use this and add figures in the appendix, the caption of the figure is something like: Figuur .1 sometexthere. What I'm also trying to accomplish is keeping what your code does and having the captions be like Figuur A.1 sometexthere.

Comment: @Silverrocker Add `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A}` after `\chapter{Test Appendix}`