# Remove chapter name or add appendix name to chapter

Tags: numbering, memoir, appendices

My document class

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,article]{memoir}
```

I want to add `Appendix` before the number so that `\chapter{An appendix}` displays `Appendix A An appendix` and not `A An appendix`

Alternatively, if I change my document class to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{memoir}
```

and remove `chapter` so that when calling a `\chapter` it only numbers

ex. `\chapter{Title 1}` results in in `1 Title 1`

My doc:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-------------------------------
    \frontmatter
        \pagenumbering{Roman}

        \tableofcontents

%-------------------------------
    \mainmatter

             \chapter{Introduction}

             \appendix
             \addappheadtotoc
             \chapter{Derivations}
             \section{Celerity at arbitrary depth}\label{sec:celerity_ar_dep}
             \includepdf[pages=59,scale=1,trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 10cm,clip]{Litteratur/Hydrodynamics2012.pdf}

%-------------------------------
    \backmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please remove everything that is not necessary to explain what your problem is. In particular, we don't have the files that you `\input`. Also, your code contains loads of packages that are irrelevant to your problem. What we need is a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60342/21891

Comment: @Jubobs I will remove what you request. Thought the full preambel wold the info need to see package collisions.

Comment: Unless I misread the question, it has nothing to do with package conflicts, so there is no harm in removing some of those `\usepackage`s.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please clarify your second sentence (*Alternatively... it only numbers*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope I haven't misunderstood the question...

If you want to add the word "Appendix" each time a chapter title is printed (inside appendices), you can add the line

```
\renewcommand*\printchaptername{\Large\bfseries\appendixname~}
```

just after issuing the `\appendix` command.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%-------------------------------
    \frontmatter
        \pagenumbering{Roman}

        \tableofcontents

%-------------------------------
    \mainmatter

             \chapter{Introduction}

             \appendix
             \addappheadtotoc
             \renewcommand*\printchaptername{\Large\bfseries\appendixname~}
             \chapter{Derivations}
             \section{Celerity at arbitrary depth}\label{sec:celerity_ar_dep}
             %\includepdf[pages=59,scale=1,trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 10cm,clip]{Litteratur/Hydrodynamics2012.pdf}

%-------------------------------
    \backmatter

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you also want the same behavior in the ToC, you can add the line

```
\renewcommand*\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
```

in the preamble.

---

Instead, if you want to use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany]{memoir}
```

you can remove the words "Chapter" and "Appendix" from chapter titles by simply adding the following line in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*\printchaptername{}
```

If you want to remove "Chapter" but not "Appendix" add also

```
\renewcommand*\printchaptername{\chapnamefont\appendixname}
```

just after issuing `\appendix`.

Comment: I'm trying to use your answer, but my compiler says that \addappheadtotoc has not been defined, and so it doesn't compile. How can I solve this?